# How to do pagination in Many to Many in Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-paginate

I have two tables `Posts` and `Tags` with `many to many` relation. I need to retrieve all posts by some tag and paginate it. Is it possible to do with `paginate` method or I need to create a new instance of `Paginator` and do everything by hand?

P.S.
Need something like:

```
$tags = Tags::where('name', '=', $tag)->with('posts')->first();

$posts = $tags->posts->paginate(5);

return view('blog/posts')->with('posts', $posts);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use:

```
$posts = $tags->posts()->paginate(5);
```

and you should also rename `$tags` to `$tag` if you are getting only one record to not make variable name misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a join statement. It should look something like this:

```
DB::table('tags')
        ->join('posts', 'tags.id', '=', 'posts.tag_id')
        ->where('tags.name', '=', $tag)
        ->paginate(5);
```